# Symfony generateUrl

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm trying the Symfony tutorial, but the generateUrl doesn't work. I've this code line in LuckyController:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl(
        'blog/show',
        array('slug' => 'my-blog-post')
    );
```

and the page: BlogController with:

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/show/{slug}")
 */
public function showAction($slug) {
    echo "hello world"; die;
}
```

if I call the /blog/show/try from browser it works, if I call it from my other route, it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Take a look at a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832163/how-to-send-params-in-url-query-string-in-symfony/43832271#43832271

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a name for your route

```
/**
 * @Route("/blog/show/{slug}", name="blog_show")
 */
public function showAction($slug) {
    echo "hello world"; die;
}
```

That's what you use to generate your URL:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl(
    'blog_show',
    array('slug' => 'my-blog-post')
);
```

Answer (score -2):

First of all, you shoudn't call in a controller method another controller method. If you need some logic to share between them, you should use a service.

Comment: I know, but I wanted try to see if I had understood!